# BEA-2156404 Unable to find a Validation Context

Tags: deployment, upgrade, weblogic12c

I need to upgrade weblogic 10.3 to 12.1.2.
You can notice the deployement was a success, and it 's the same errors' block for all modules af application, when the state goes from 'is transitionning state' to 'successfully transitioned state'.
The server is running successfully; but I had this error:

```
<Oct 8, 2014 10:43:31 AM CEST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149060> <Module resp of application blwebapp successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server server1.> 
<Oct 8, 2014 10:43:31 AM CEST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149059> <Module app-sup of application blwebapp is transitioning from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server server1.> 



<Oct 8, 2014 10:43:31 AM CEST> <Info> <org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver> <BEA-000000> <Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.> 
<Oct 8, 2014 10:43:31 AM CEST> <Error> <Weblogic-Validation> <BEA-2156404> <Unable to find a Validation Context. java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: String index out of range: -1
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: String index out of range: -1
    at weblogic.validation.ValidationContextManager.getValidationContext(ValidationContextManager.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.WlsBinder.<init>(WlsBinder.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.WlsBinder.getInstance(WlsBinder.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser$1.run(ValidationXmlParser.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser$1.run(ValidationXmlParser.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser.<init>(ValidationXmlParser.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:143)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:117)
    at weblogic.validation.injection.ValidationManager.getDefaultValidationBean(ValidationManager.java:179)
    at weblogic.validation.injection.ValidationManager.bindValidation(ValidationManager.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindValidation(EnvironmentBuilder.java:500)
    at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindValidation(EnvironmentBuilder.java:492)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:194)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:2797)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1648)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:804)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:317)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:313)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:121)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:222)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:414)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:191)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:99)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: javax.naming.NamingException: String index out of range: -1
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:311)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
    at weblogic.validation.ValidationContextManager.getValidationContext(ValidationContextManager.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.WlsBinder.<init>(WlsBinder.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.WlsBinder.getInstance(WlsBinder.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser$1.run(ValidationXmlParser.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser$1.run(ValidationXmlParser.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser.<init>(ValidationXmlParser.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:143)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:117)
    at weblogic.validation.injection.ValidationManager.getDefaultValidationBean(ValidationManager.java:179)
    at weblogic.validation.injection.ValidationManager.bindValidation(ValidationManager.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindValidation(EnvironmentBuilder.java:500)
    at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindValidation(EnvironmentBuilder.java:492)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:194)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:2797)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1648)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:804)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:317)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:313)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:121)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:222)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:414)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:191)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:99)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
>
```

After this, server stopped ! I don't know why!

Could someone help me, please ?

Thanks,
Awa

Comment: I assume you haven't found an answer to this issue?